# Rename branch 'a' to master

Tags: git, gerrit

How do I rename a branch 'a' to 'master' and rename 'master' to 'b' in gerrit?

I have recently switched to gerrit from a shared git repository.

Comment: there are no options for renaming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create the "b" branch from master using the web UI:  "Admin" -> "Projects" -> "YourProject" -> "Branches".  Enter "b" for "Branch Name", and "master" as "Initial Revision", then click the "Create Branch" button.

Now to replace what `master` is referencing, you have to have "force push" permission on the project, then do:

```
$ git checkout a
$ git push --force gerrit a:master
```

This will **replace** the entire history of the "master" branch with that of the local "a" branch.  So **be very careful with this, and be sure that's what you want to do**.

Finally if you want to remove the 'a' branch in Gerrit, once again go to the web UI's project management screen (same as above), tick the box next to the "a" branch, then click the "Delete" button.

Comment: If you're working on GitHub you can do git push --force <clone url of your repo> a:master

Comment: The `git push --force <origin> <localBranch>:<remoteBrance>` command is not git-server-specific: it works for Gerrit, GitHub, a local file-path git repo, a remote ssh URL, or any other git remote.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about gerrit, but generally in git you rename branches by

```
git branch -m old_branch new_branch
```